# How to aggregate with many conditions on MongoDB. Double $lookup etc

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

How to display "hardest category" based on in which "study" size of notLearnedWords was the highest. MongoDB Aggregation

I have these 3 models:

1. Study
2. WordSet
3. Category

**Study model has reference into WordSet, then WordSet has reference into Category.**

And based on Studies i'm displaying statistics.

How i can display "The hardest category" based on size of "notLearnedWords" was the highest?

I don't know on which place i should start with that querying.

For now i display "hardestCategory" as element that is most used.

I think that condition would look something like this:

```
{ $max: { $size: '$notLearnedWords' } } // size of the study with most notLearnedWords
```

I would achieve a response like this:

```
"stats": [
    {
        "_id": null,
        "numberOfStudies": 4,
        "averageStudyTime": 82.5,
        "allStudyTime": 330,
        "longestStudy": 120,
        "allLearnedWords": 8
        "hardestCategory": "Work" // only this field is missing
    }
]
```

I've tried to do it like this:

```
const stats = await Study.aggregate([
  { $match: { user: new ObjectID(currentUserId) } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'users',
      localField: 'user',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'currentUser',
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'wordsets',
      let: { wordSetId: '$learnedWordSet' },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$_id', '$$wordSetId'] } } },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            category: 1,
          },
        },
        { $unwind: '$category' },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: '$category',
            count: { $sum: 1 },
          },
        },
        { $sort: { count: -1 } },
        { $limit: 1 },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'categories',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: '_id',
            as: 'category',
          },
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            category: { $arrayElemAt: ['$category.name', 0] },
          },
        },
      ],
      as: 'wordSet',
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      numberOfStudies: { $sum: 1 },
      averageStudyTime: { $avg: '$studyTime' },
      allStudyTime: { $sum: '$studyTime' },
      longestStudy: { $max: '$studyTime' },
      allLearnedWords: {
        $sum: { $size: '$learnedWords' },
      },
      hardestCategory: {
        $first: {
          $first: '$wordSet.category',
        },
      },
      studyWithMostNotLearnedWords: { $max: { $size: '$notLearnedWords' } },
    },
  },
]);
```

Study

```
     const studySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
  studyTime: {
    type: Number,
  },
  learnedWords: [String],
  notLearnedWords: [String],
  learnedWordSet: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'WordSet',
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});
```

WordSet

```
const wordSetSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: {
        type: String,
      },
      category: {
        type: [
          {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Category',
            required: true,
          },
        ],
      },
    });
```

Category

```
const categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
  },
});
```

Comment: Looks like you could benefit from a relational database, tbh.

Comment: I know but i'm using MongoDB. This is last think that i need to finish my project..